# Create a range from every nth cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a function that returns a range consisting of every nth cell of the range that was passed to it as an argument.

```
Function OFFSETRANGE(AREA As Range, Optional STEP As Integer = 1) As Range
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim TempRange As Range

For Each rCell In AREA.Cells
    If Counter Mod Counter = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("In loop" & Counter & " " & rCell)
        TempRange = Application.Union(TempRange, rCell)
    End If
Next
OFFSETRANGE = TempRange
End Function
```

I get a #VALUE error whenever I try to use the function. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Did you declare somewhere in your code what the value of a `Counter` is? I would also `Debug.Print` each cell in `Area.Cells` just to see and make sure that each one of them has a data in it.

Comment: You cannot use Union on an empty Range (one which is Nothing), and you're not incrementing `Counter`.  Debug your function by calling it from a Sub in VBA instead of from a worksheet.

Comment: how are you using the function?

Answer (score 2):

```
Function OFFSETRANGE(AREA As Range, Optional theStep As Integer = 1) As Range

    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim TempRange As Range, rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In AREA.Cells
        Counter = Counter + 1
        If Counter Mod theStep = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "In loop" & Counter & " " & rCell
            'check if we can use Union or not here
            If TempRange Is Nothing Then
                Set TempRange = rCell 
            Else
                Set TempRange = Application.Union(TempRange, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set OFFSETRANGE = TempRange

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here

`If Counter Mod Counter = 0 Then`

But `Counter` doesn't have a value thus throwing a value error.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things look incorrect.

1) Your "counter" integer isn't set and since you're doing a mod value with itself it will ALWAYS equal 0 even if it did have a value. Perhaps you mean Counter Mod step? In below sample, I set counter = 2, but you can obviously change.

2) The union will fail the first effort. Best way to deal with this is with an if statement if nothing. I include a sample below.

```
Function OFFSETRANGE(AREA As Range, Optional STEP As Integer = 1) As Range
Dim Counter As Integer: Counter = 2
Dim TempRange As Range, rCell As Range

For Each rCell In AREA.Cells
    If Counter Mod STEP = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("In loop" & Counter & " " & rCell)

        If TempRange Is Nothing Then
            Set TempRange = rCell
        Else
            Set TempRange = Union(TempRange, rCell)
        End If

    End If

Next
Set OFFSETRANGE = TempRange
End Function
```